# SwiftUI, Xcode 13, Question about .filter'ing CoreData

Tags: core-data, swiftui

```
@FetchRequest(
        entity: Client.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [])
    private var clients: FetchedResults<Client>

(...)

var searchResults: FetchedResults<Client> {
            if searchText.isEmpty {
                return clients
            } else {
                return clients.filter({$0.name!.contains(searchText)}) // Error here!
            }
        }

(...)

ForEach(searchResults, id: \.self) { client in

(...)
```

Error

```
Cannot convert return expression of type '[FetchedResults<Client>.Element]' (aka 'Array<Client>') to return type 'FetchedResults<Client>'
```

Hi,

I'm not sure how my logic is wrong. Could someone please tell me how to fix searchResults?

Also, is this the more efficient way to filter results or should I filter in the ForEach()? It seems pretty slow when I put the filter in ForEach()

Comment: Maybe `return Array(clients.filter{ ...})`? But you might want to apply the filter inside the fetch request instead of after. Imagine, you have 500k elements, you retrieve the 500k then filter to get only 100, but you could filter on the request, getting only the 100.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did as you suggested: I'm fetching filtered data instead of filtering the fetched data.

Answer (score 1):

While I know you have a code fix, and it is the correct one, I wanted to answer the question for posterity as I have run into this myself. The logic is wrong simply because your `searchResults` var is of type `FetchedResults<Client>`, but a filter returns an Array. So, the error message is telling you exactly the problem. You are trying to return an `[Client]` as a `FetchedResults<Client>` so you have a type mismatch.

You have two solutions:

1. You can filter in the fetch request, which is how you solved it per @Larme suggestion. This is especially helpful if you only need the filtered results in the UI and/or you have a lot of results.
2. You can filter when you use your fetched results. This is useful when you want your user to be able to determine what is filtered out by their own selections, but you don't know what filtering they will want ahead of time or that regardless of the filtering you are doing, you may need the whole FetchRequest later.